# How to clean wicker plate-holder?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

Paper plates can be too flimsy for heavy food, or too hot to hold if the food is hot, so we have some wicker plate holders to use underneath them. Occasionally I'll  find a plate holder on the floor or something. I know it shouldn't come in contact with food but I'd still rather have it clean.

Wiping it off might get it kind of clean, but it's hard to get a paper towel between the strands. I'm afraid to wash it in the sink or dishwasher because I don't know how immersion affects wicker.

Answer (score 3):

Wicker accessories and furniture are woven when the wicker was wet and flexible after being totally soaked. If it gets soiled or a bit grungy, quickly rinse it under a sprinkler or give it a quick soak and brush it clean. Avoid soaking it for a long time. Soap will soften the fibres making them limp unless you can rinse soap or detergent out completely. Dish washer is overkill and will probably hurt the weave with water pressure from the rotor.

Set it aside to dry and it will be good to go after it dries.

Good luck.

Comment: To _sanitize_ them, you could use rubbing alcohol instead of water or soap-and-water. If you do use soap, realize that some soap will soak into the fibers. When you rinse, you won't just rinse the soap off the surfaces of the fibers (which is quick). You will have to rinse out the soap that has soaked into the fibers (which will take a longer time). Maybe only put soap directly on the spot(s) that are visibly dirty.

Comment: Willow withies require a few hours of soaking before working, up to more than 48 hours for the biggest ones. Washing and even soaking for a few minutes in doing dishes will not soften it much. As long as you let it completely dry when done.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to assume this is similar to cleaning wicker furniture. The individual wicker strands might be thinner and the weave different, but the idea is still the same as it's s till the same materials, whether it's real wicker or synthetic.

> For routine cleaning of wicker that's made of bamboo, rattan, or willow, brush off or vacuum as much of the surface dirt as you can. Then wash it with a soft brush and soapy water to which you've added one or two teaspoons of ammonia. Rinse well and let the piece dry outdoors in the sun.
>
> To remove grime from wicker furniture that's a more than just dusty, use a mild oil-base soap, such as Murphy Oil Soap, mixed with warm water. For a homemade cleaner, mix 1⁄4 cup ammonia, 2 tablespoons white vinegar, and 1 quart warm water. Follow any ventilation recommendations and other precautions outlined by the ammonia manufacturer on the bottle.

https://www.bhg.com/homekeeping/house-cleaning/surface/caring-for-wicker-furniture/

There are other sites that recommend similar ways to clean, some include equal parts of vinegar and water, so there's plenty of ways to make this work, and you evidently aren't going to hurt it with water. Remember that lots of patio furniture is made from wicker and is left outside in any weather purposefully.